# yachalk/chalk conflicts with str.format method for fixed-width strings

Tags: python, string, colors, output

In Python, I want to both (a) use the [str.format method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) to print strings with a fixed width and (b) use [yachalk/chalk](https://github.com/bluenote10/yachalk) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428529/8401379)) to color the output sent to the terminal.

When I use str.format without yachalk, I successfully achieve the fixed-width output. However, when I add yachalk to the mix, I get the colored output I seek, but the strings all run together, ignoring the fixed-width formatting.

Here's my test-case code, followed by screenshot of the terminal output.

Am I doing something wrong? Is yachalk incompatible with str.format?

```
from yachalk import chalk
s1 = "e4"
s2 = "c5"
s3 = "Nf3"
s = '{:8}'.format(s1) + '{:8}'.format(s2) + '{:8}'.format(s3)
c1 = chalk.yellow(s1)
c2 = chalk.yellow(s2)
c3 = chalk.yellow(s3)
c = '{:8}'.format(c1) + '{:8}'.format(c2) + '{:8}'.format(c3)
print(s)
print(c)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Even though I couldn't apply `str.format` method to the output of `yachalk`, I could apply the `str.format` method *first* and then apply `yachalk`.

```
from yachalk import chalk
s1 = "e4"
s2 = "c5"
s3 = "Nf3"
s = '{:8}'.format(s1) + '{:8}'.format(s2) + '{:8}'.format(s3)
c1 = chalk.yellow('{:8}'.format(s1))
c2 = chalk.yellow('{:8}'.format(s2))
c3 = chalk.yellow('{:8}'.format(s3))
c = c1 + c2 + c3
print(s)
print(c)
```

See output as pasted graphic:

[image]